# Comparing 2 Columns until the 1st "."

Tags: sql, algorithm

I am new to SQL programming and I am trying to figure out how to get a report to show a mismatch in System Names & DNS Names. Both of the columns are in a table called nodes.

System Name router-1-dc and the DNS would be router-1-dc.domain I am trying to find Nodes that don't match to the "." prior to the domain example for this would be
System Name "router-1-datacenter" and DNS Name "router-1-dc.domain" I would want this example to show on the report page.

The tricky part is that some of the system names have the ".domain" and some don't.

Here is the SQL Query I built however it does not appear to be working as I need it too.

```
SELECT N. NodeID, N.Caption, N.SysName, N.DNS, N.IP_Address, N.Device_Type
FROM (
SELECT Nodes.NodeID, Nodes.Caption, Nodes.SysName, Nodes.DNS, Nodes.Device_Type, Nodes.IP_Address
FROM Nodes
WHERE CHARINDEX('.',Nodes.SysName)>0 AND CHARINDEX('.',Nodes.DNS)>0
) N
WHERE SUBSTRING(N.SysName, 1, CHARINDEX('.',N.SysName)-1) <> SUBSTRING(N.DNS, 1, CHARINDEX('.',N.DNS)-1)
AND N.Device_Type = 'UPS'

ORDER BY 5 ASC, 2 ASC
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Can you show examples of system names and DNS names that do and do not match (by editing your question)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, or something like it (I've no data to test it against):

```
SELECT N.NodeID, N.Caption, N.SysName, N.DNS, N.IP_Address, N.Device_Type
 from Nodes N
 where left(n.sysname, charindex('.', n.sysname + '.') - 1 )
    <> left(n.dns, charindex('.', n.dns + '.') - 1)
 order by N.IP_Address, N.Caption
```

The trick is to add a "." to the end of each string for evaluation purposes. If there already is a period in the string, this has no effect, otherwist you get the whole string.